# I need to modify script to hide and show divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to modify a script to do the following:

Hide `div`s 'sbdomainSubGroup' and 'sbdomainSubGroups' after page reload if no value is selected from drop-down 'sbdomain'.

Show `div` 'sbdomainSubGroup' if "Yes" is selected from drop-down 'sbdomain' when page is reloaded. Also, to retain `text` field 'business' value.

Show `div` 'sbdomainSubGroups' if "No" is selected from drop-down 'sbdomain' when page is reloaded. Also to retain `text` field 'business2' value.

I am aware that `localStorage` or `cookies` can be used to achieve this but I am new to JavaScript/JQuery.

It would be great if I could just stick to JavaScript to get this done.

```js
window.onload = showHide;

function showHide(){
    var el = document.getElementById("sbdomain");
    var selectedVal = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
    var subGroupEl = document.getElementById("SubGroup").getElementsByTagName("div");
 var subGroupFl = document.getElementById("SubGroups").getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i=0; i<subGroupEl.length; i++){
        subGroupEl[i].className = "hidden";
  subGroupFl[i].className = "hidden";
    }
    if(document.getElementById(selectedVal))
        document.getElementById(selectedVal).className = "visible";
 
        
    else
        console.log("No Sub Groups present for this option");
}
```

```css
.hidden{display: none;}
.visible{display: block;}
```

```html
Is this to be a subdomain?
<select id="sbdomain" name="sbdomain">
<option disabled selected>Please Select</option>
  <option value="sbdomainSubGroup">Yes</option>
  <option value="sbdomainSubGroups">No</option>
</select>

<div id="SubGroup">
<div id="sbdomainSubGroup" name="sbdomainSubGroup">
  <label id="subdomain">Enter Subdomain</label>
  <input type='text' class='text' name='business' size='20'/>
  <br />
  
</div>
</div>

<div id="SubGroups">
<div id="sbdomainSubGroups" name="sbdomainSubGroups">
  <label id="subdomainno">Enter Domain</label>
  <input type='text' class='text' name='business2' size='20'/>
  <br />
  
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On change of your drop down value call a JavaScript function.

In that function check what value is selected by the user. Based on the selected value set your className hidden /visible to the div sbdomainSubGroup/sbdomainSubGroups respectively.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index777</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }

        .visible {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            window.onload = showHide;

            function showHide() {
                //Hide divs sbdomainSubGroup and sbdomainSubGroups after page reload if no value
                //is selected from dropdown sbdomain.
                if ($("#sbdomain option:selected").text() == "Please Select") {
                    $("#sbdomainSubGroup").addClass("hidden");
                    $("#sbdomainSubGroups").addClass("hidden");
                }
                else {
                    $("#sbdomainSubGroup").removeClass("hidden");
                    $("#sbdomainSubGroups").removeClass("hidden");
                }

                //Show div sbdomainSubGroup if "Yes" is selected from dropdown sbdomain when page is
                //reloaded. Also to retain textfield business value.
                if ($("#sbdomain option:selected").text() == "Yes") {
                    $("#sbdomainSubGroup").removeClass("hidden");
                    $("#sbdomainSubGroups").addClass("hidden");
                }

                //Show div sbdomainSubGroups if "No" is selected from dropdown sbdomain when page is
                //reloaded. Also to retain textfield business2 value.
                if ($("#sbdomain option:selected").text() == "No") {
                    $("#sbdomainSubGroups").removeClass("hidden");
                    $("#sbdomainSubGroup").addClass("hidden");
                }
            }
            //this represents a page reload
            $("#reload").click(function () {
                showHide();
            })
        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    Is this to be a subdomain?
    <select id="sbdomain" name="sbdomain">
        <option selected>Please Select</option>
        <option value="sbdomainSubGroup">Yes</option>
        <option value="sbdomainSubGroups">No</option>
    </select>

    <div id="SubGroup">
        <div id="sbdomainSubGroup" name="sbdomainSubGroup">
            <label id="subdomain">Enter Subdomain</label>
            <input type='text' class='text' name='business' size='20' />
            <br />

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="SubGroups">
        <div id="sbdomainSubGroups" name="sbdomainSubGroups">
            <label id="subdomainno">Enter Domain</label>
            <input type='text' class='text' name='business2' size='20' />
            <br />

        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="BtnRepresentsPageReload" id="reload" />
</body>
</html>
```